# android error: map cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, google-maps, sdk, google-maps-android-api-2, r.java-file

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) to learn how to use googleMaps API.

But in MainAntivity.java it gives me an error I'm not sure how to solve:

```
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

I get `map cannot be resolved or is not a field` but it reffers to: `d(R.id.map)`

Any ideas why map in R.id.map is failing??

**EDIT :**

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mapsv2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
private GoogleMap map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (map!=null){
       Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG).title("Hamburg"));
       Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
           .position(KIEL)
           .title("Kiel")
           .snippet("Kiel is cool")
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
               .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
        }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<permission
    android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mapsv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your_apikey" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: insufficient information to debug or resolve your problem?

Comment: Put xml and java code

Comment: Ok, I'll edit now with my java and xml

Comment: have you added google play service libs? also paste  xml file above

Comment: yes, or at least I think so, if I didn't private GoogleMap would fail, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented the Fragment in XML file? Refer [this blog](http://androidtutorial4u.blogspot.in/search/label/google%20map%20v2%20%28Android%29)

Comment: Just eddited quetion to include java and xml

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

1.Replace this code
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

 With this
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

2.Add this permission in AndroidManifest file
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Note : if you are using latest google-play-services jar for map then you have to also define below meta-data in your AndroidManifest file
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="4030500" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using below code

xml

```
<fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {    

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting a reference to the map
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also your app should extend FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` activity_maps.xml